# select null values in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, null

I have two tables

1. xx_new.xx_online_registrations@appsread.prd.com oreg
2. m_warranty_sku MSK

In oreg table i have some null values for the field ora_warranty_id, but in MSK table i have no null values, so when i join these two tables the null values column for oreg are filtered, is there a way i can caputre that data as well. I was doing the qry below but not sure if that is correct.

```
select *
from
    (
    select 
   oreg.ora_warranty_id,
   mdh.warranty_sku_num
    from
     mdhdba.m_warranty_sku mdh
         , xx_new.xx_online_registrations@appsread.prd.com oreg
    where
   mdh.warranty_sku_num= oreg.ora_warranty_id(+) -----ora_warranty_id from  xx_new.xx_online_registration table
   )
where ora_warranty_id is  null -- oreg.ora_warranty_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
    select *
from
    (
    select 
   oreg.ora_warranty_id,
   mdh.warranty_sku_num
    from
     mdhdba.m_warranty_sku mdh
         , xx_new.xx_online_registrations@appsread.prd.com oreg
    where
   oreg.ora_warranty_id = mdh.warranty_sku_num(+) -----ora_warranty_id from  xx_new.xx_online_registration table
   )
where ora_warranty_id is  null -- oreg.ora_warranty_id
```

Comment: So full outer join will bring all the records from only oreg.ora_warranty_id  table, i think that brings all the records from MDH table as well , pelase correct me if i am wrong. I am only intereted in all the records from OREG table as there might be soem records in MDH table that are not in OREG table and i don't need those recs.

Comment: U want all the records from oreg table. Ok then do reveresely. Refer to my answer now.

Comment: Now oreg table will act as a left table and you will get matching records from both tables as well all records from oreg table. If you find this ans or post useful and vote it up. THanks

Comment: Is this query not the same as leaving out the join completely?